# Ubuntu On Windows Without Internet

Tags: wubi

I tried to use Wubi, but there is no option to choose the ISO image or anything like that. It requires an internet connection.

How should I install Ubuntu without internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Ubuntu ISO image, Wubi is already part of it.
You can either burn a disc and load it inside Windows or mount the ISO image in Windows using programs like [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, if Wubi and the ISO are in the same directory, Wubi will automatically find the ISO and use it.